# Recurring Date with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hoping to create a recurring date using Javascript - with the date to display on a website. The recurring date is to be calculated from a given start date.

- Given Start Date (For Example 1 January 2020)
- Recurring date to be calculated every 7 days from the start date (For example 8 January, 15 January etc.) with no end date
- The next date (from today's date) is to be displayed on the website

If today was 7 January 2020, text would read "next event date is 8 January 2020"

If today was 9 January 2020, text would read "next event date is 15 January 2020" and so on.

Coming from an HTML/CSS background so appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: if it's `7th Jan` it should be `13th Jan` as per your req but you mentioned `8th Jan` ? did i understood it wrong ?

Comment: @Codenewbie it is a weekly recurrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let startDate="1 July 2020"
let startDateObj=new Date(startDate)

let recurringDay=7

let today=new Date()

let totalDays=Math.ceil((today-startDateObj)/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
let daysLeftToRecur=(recurringDay+1- totalDays%recurringDay) ||recurringDay

let nextDate=new Date(new Date().getTime()+(daysLeftToRecur*24*60*60*1000));
//nextDate is in ISO format and you can format it accordingly
console.log("Next event is on ", nextDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'))
// dd/mm/yyyy format
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Here is a sample code:

```
function computeNextDate(date, addDays){
    return "next event date is "  + new Date(date.getTime() + (addDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

```
const todayDate = new Date();
const addTotalDays = 7;
for(let i=1; i< 100; i++){
 console.log(computeNextDate(todayDate, i * addTotalDays));
}
```

The question is bit unclear. I have done it with a for loop. But you could use `computeNextDate` for any "next event" computation.

Comment: Do these scripts need to be merged, I cannot return any dates?

Comment: Yes. Please merge the scripts